# Parse date with AEDT time zone in java

Tags: java, android, parsing, date

I am trying to parse a string of format

```
Sat Feb 01 15:00:19 AEDT 2014
```

into date object. My code looks like following:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
try{
    Date time = parserSDF.parse("Sat Feb 01 15:00:19 AEDT 2014");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I am getting a 'parse error'. I cannot change the input format of the date and I also cannot set my timezone to a static value as this code is to be run on andorid device. How can I parse this string into date ?

Answer (score 1):

"AEDT" is a 4-letter timezone which is not supported. That causes the exception. 
Only the [valid timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) can be parsed.

You can use (GMT+11) instead of AEDT as shown below:

```
    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
    parserSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+11"));
    try{
        Date time = parserSDF.parse("Sat Feb 01 15:00:19 2014");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "exception: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: As this code is to be run in an android device, the time zone can vary and also apparently there are other 4 letter time zones. Is there any way to parse these string ?

Comment: @EddardStark: [Android doesn't allow](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html) 4-letter time zones. If you have seen any 4-letter timezone being used, please share. Timezone won't vary on device because we set it through progmatically in above code -  **parserSDF.setTimeZone**. If you want to get by region names, [you can get it using this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24846843/2982225).